# Is it bad practice to have my getter method change the stored value?

Tags: class, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation, getter-setter

Is it bad practice to change my getter method like version 2 in my class.

Version 1:

```
 public String getMyValue(){
     return this.myValue
 }
```

Version 2:

```
 public String getMyValue(){

    if(this.myValue == null || this.myValue.isEmpty()){
       this.myValue = "N/A";
    }

    return this.myValue;
 }
```

Comment: imho it's ok if this side effect is clearly documented in the docs

Comment: I prefer that `getter` functions will never change the object's value. You can perform this check in other function and set the value of it in a `setter` function. Just to have a clear code.

Comment: I don't think, this is a major problem. This is ok, but clear cut java doc must be provided before the method .

Comment: Getting a value should not have side-effects.

Comment: I think this is bad because it seems like you are mixing your presenting with your data model. What happens when your app need to be translated to a different language?.

Comment: I'm not found of your change, but *generally* I think changing a getter is OK. After all, the getter is an abstraction that *enables* us to change the internal behavior w/o breaking other code.

Comment: `myvalue` in the if is spelt with lower case 'v', twice. Is it intentional?

Comment: Shouldn't the question title read, `Is it bad practice for a getter to change an object's member's value?`, as it is it sounds like you are asking whether it's bad for a getter's internal implementation to change, to which I believe the answer is no, it's ok to change it.

Comment: The setter should be the only thing that changes the property's value. This is to say the getter should call the setter to alter the value. Why? Because the setter may also do things to the internal state and bypassing the setter may leave the instance in a conflicted or invalid state.

Comment: An example of where you get the _prior_ value of a variable while also setting it to a new value is the test-and-set operation. This is typically done atomically for thread-safety and commonly operates on booleans. The x86 instruction set includes such an operation (BTS). Earliest I can remember personally is the VAX 11 BBSSI (Branch on Bit Set and Set Interlocked) instruction, from the late '70s.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

I think it is actually quite a bad practice if your **getter** methods change the internal state of the object.

To achieve the same I would suggest just *returning* the `"N/A"`.

- Generally speaking this internal field might be used in other places (internally) for which you don't need to use the getter method. So in the end, the call to `foo.getMyValue()` could actually change the behaviour of `foo`.

Alternatively, the translation from `null` to `"N/A"` could be done in the **setter**, i.e. the internal value could be set to `"N/A"` if `null` is passed.

---

A general remark:
I would only add states such as `"N/A"` if they are expected by some API or other instance relying on your code. If that is not the case you should rely on the standard null types that are available to you in your programming language.

Comment: Just a note: I feel that getters can change the internal state of an object in the case of lazy-loading, where you specifically want to load data only when the getter gets called.

Comment: Fair enough, that is a valid use-case. But the situation described by OP could lead to horrible side-effects.

Comment: There is nothing more annoying than dealing with a Property that changes state on the getter, and having the state change while debugging every time some component of the debugger access it.

Comment: I don't think there's any issue with changing the internal state of an object in a getter. The internal state of an object is the class author's business. As a user of the class, you are not supposed to know (or care) what's happening internally, **as long as the external interface is consistent**. So whether he sets the value in the setter or, lazily, in the getter, this is completely valid. What's important is that the getter consistently returns N/A for null or empty values.

Comment: Agree with @Laurent this is simply lazy initialization of the instance variable and is quite common practice. Not sure about checking against `.isEmpty()` though, or even using `"N/A"` as the default value (I'd probably prefer a Null Object or an exception, because the value/treatment for the default case often depends on the calling side, not just the called object)

Comment: @Laurent Yes of course the main concern should be that the external interface of a class is well written and consistent. But the question was about *bad coding practice*. I assure you I can write totally valid classes using the most horrid of coding practices.

Comment: @fgysin, essentially the question is "is it ok to set a value in a getter" and the answer is yes, and it's frequently done for lazy initialization. I can't comment on his particular example since there's no context, but in general lazy initialization is not a "horrid coding practice".

Comment: @Laurent I'm not saying that lazy initialization is a bad practice. Just wanted to state that the question about coding practices is somewhat independent from the question whether the final class/entity offers valid & consistent interfaces.

Answer (score 38):

In my opinion, unless you are doing `lazy-loading` (which you are not in that case), getters should not change the value. So I would either:

Put the change in the setter

```
public void setMyValue(String value) {
    if(value == null || value.isEmpty()){
        this.myValue = "N/A";
    } else {
        this.myValue = value;
    }
}
```

Or make the getter return a default value if value not set properly:

```
public String getMyValue() {
    if(this.myvalue == null || this.myvalue.isEmpty()){
        return "N/A";
    }    
    return this.myValue;
}
```

In the case of lazy-loading, where I would say that changing your members in a getter is fine, you would do something like:

```
public String getMyValue() {
    if (this.myvalue == null) {
        this.myvalue = loadMyValue();
    }    
    return this.myValue;
}
```

Comment: Why would you call your lazy loading method get...()? Calling it something like load...() seems more appropriate, doesn't it?

Comment: Because the getter returns the value directly **unless** it has never been loaded before (hence the call to `loadMyValue` inside the getter). Calling the getter loadMyValue would imply (according to me) that it loads the value no matter what.

Answer (score 12):

No. You're doing two things here. Getting and setting.

Comment: I actually prefer the accepted answer. It states that you could return the value "N/A" instead of changing the class variable first.

Answer (score 11):

Yes. It's a **bad practice.**

Why?

When the value is set (in a constructor or setter method), it should be validated, not when a getter method is called. Creating a `private` `validate*` method for this is also a good idea.

```
private boolean validateThisValue(String a) {
     return this.myValue != null && !this.myValue.isEmpty();
}

public void setThisValue(String a) {
    if (validateThisValue(a)) {
        this.myValue = a;
    } 
    else {
        // do something else
        // in this example will be
        this.myValue = "N/A";
    }
}
```

And, in the getter method, never ever change the state of the object. I have worked on some projects, and the getter often must be made `const`: "this method cannot change internal state".

At least, if you do not want to complicate things, in the getter method, you should **return** `"N/A"` rather than **change** internal state and set `myValue` to `"N/A"`.

Comment: I disagree with never changing a value in a setter.  The entire purpose of using getter/setters is to abstract internal and external implementations.  `Person.setHeightInCentimeters(int value)`, `Person.setHeightInMeters(double value)`, and `Person.setHeightInFeetAndInches(int feet, int inches)` should all share a single internal representation, meaning that at least two of them will be storing something other than the input value(s).

Comment: ah. i'm sorry so much :( i type mismatch, never change something in getter. not setter. as you see in my code, i have change internal state of setter. i have edited. i'm sorry so much.

Answer (score 6):

I usually define a specific `getter`.

Never alter original `getter`:

```
 public String getMyValue(){
     return this.myValue
 }
```

And create a specific `getter`:

```
public String getMyValueFormatted(){

    if(this.myvalue == null || this.myvalue.isEmpty()){
       return "N/A";
    }else{
       return this.myValue;
    }
 }
```

Comment: How do you know which one to call when?

Comment: The intent of the second method is for the purpose of display to user.

Comment: So then the 1st one should not be a public?

Comment: No. Both are public. Uses first to get raw value. When needs formatted value, use the second one. Simple, you don't need complicate `getter/setter` methods.

Comment: It would be confusing for a new developer who is calling the API. 1st approach: Rename 1st public method as getMyValueOriginal and 2nd method as getMyValueFormatted.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's better to initialize `this.myValue = "N/A"`. And subsequent calls to `setMyValue` should modify the `this.myValue` according to your business conditions.
The `getMyValue` shouldn't modify in any way `this.myValue`. If your needs are to return a certain value, you should return that value (like "N/A") and not alter `this.myValue` . Getters must not modify member's value.

Answer (score 4):

I would change better the setter method so, if the value is `null` or empty, the `N/A` is assigned to the attribute. So, if you use the attribute in other methods inside the class (v.g. `toString()`) you will have the intended value there.

Alternatively, change the setter method to launch an exception when the value being set is not right, so the programmer is forced to improve its handling prior to setting the value.

Other than that, it is ok.

Answer (score 4):

I do feel this is a *bad practice* unless and until you explain the reason why it is so necessary for you modify the object inside the getter method instead of doing it inside the setter method.
Do you feel this cannot be done for some reason? Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 4):

Do what ever you like. After all getters and setters are just another public methods. You could use any other names.

But if you use frameworks like `Spring`, you are bound to use those standard names and you should never put your custom codes inside them.

Answer (score 4):

absolutely yes, it's a bad pratice.

Imagine you communicate accross network with a third party (remoting, COM, ...), this will increase the round-trip and then hit application performance.

Answer (score 4):

A setter could modify as part of validation, but a getter should return the value and let the validation be done by the caller. If you **do** validate, then how should be documented.

Answer (score 3):

This actually highly depends on the contract you want to enforce with your get()-method. According to design-by-contract conventions the caller has to make sure that the preconditions are met (which means doing a validation in a setter method often is actually bad design) and the callee (I do not know if that's the correct english term for that, i.e., the called one) makes sure that the post conditions are met.

If you define your contract so that the get()-method is not allowed to change the object then you are breaking your own contract. Think about implementing a method like

```
public isValid() {
    return (this.myvalue == null || this.myvalue.isEmpty());
}
```

Advantage of this approach is that you do not have to check wether the return of your get() is "N/A" or something else. This also can be called before calling set() to validate that you do not insert illegal values into your object.

If you want to set a default value you should do that during initialization.

Answer (score 3):

State changes in getters should be a hanging offence.  It means that client code must be careful about the order in which it accesses getters and setters and to do this it must have knowledge of the implementation.  You should be able to call the getters in any order and still get the same results.  A related problem occurs when the setter modifies the incoming value depending on the current state of the object.

Comment: Exactly! If you need some rope, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You can use some value holder for this purpose. Like Optional class in guava library.